# Improve performance of mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I have a mysql sql select that's taking way to long to return data.

**Tables**

```
╔════════════════╗    ╔════════════════╗
║ ITEM           ║    ║ Workspace      ║
╠════════════════║    ╠════════════════║
║ id             ║    ║ id             ║
║ guid           ║    ║ guid           ║
║ workspace_id   ║    ║ company_id     ║
║ deleted        ║    ║ deleted        ║
╚════════════════╝    ╚════════════════╝
Indexes: id, guid     Indexes: id, guid,
 workspace_id          company_id


╔════════════════╗    ╔════════════════════╗
║ COMPANY        ║    ║ item_category_xref ║
╠════════════════║    ╠════════════════════║
║ id             ║    ║ item_id            ║
║ deleted        ║    ║ category_id        ║
╚════════════════╝    ╚════════════════════╝
Indexes: id           Indexes: item_id, category_id

╔════════════════╗    ╔═════════════════════╗
║ item_image     ║    ║ tracking_action     ║
╠════════════════║    ╠═════════════════════║
║ item_id        ║    ║ id                  ║
║ sequence       ║    ║ guid                ║
╚════════════════╝    ║ action              ║
Indexes:              ║ context             ║
 (item_id, sequence)  ║ deleted             ║
                      ╚═════════════════════╝
```

**SQL**

```
    SELECT
        itm.id "item.id",
        ws.id "workspace.id", 
        co.id "company.id", 
       ((SELECT count(*) FROM item_category_xref icx
          WHERE icx.item_id = itm.id
            AND icx.featured = 1) > 0) "featured",
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tracking_action ta1
          WHERE ta1.context = 'ITEM'
            AND ta1.context_guid = itm.guid
            AND ta1.action = 'VIEW') ta_view_count ,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tracking_action ta2
          WHERE ta2.context = 'ITEM'
            AND ta2.context_guid = itm.guid
            AND ta2.action = 'SEARCH_RESULT') ta_search_count 
     FROM item itm 
     JOIN workspace ws
            ON itm.workspace_id = ws.id
            AND ws.deleted != 1
     JOIN company co
            ON ws.company_id = co.id
            AND co.deleted != 1
     JOIN item_category_xref icx
            ON itm.id = icx.item_id
            AND icx.category_id = 1
     LEFT JOIN item_image ii
            ON itm.id = ii.item_id
            AND ii.sequence = 1 
    WHERE itm.deleted != 1 
   HAVING featured > 0;
```

**EXPLAIN**
[image: SQL EXPLAIN]

This query is a result of my efforts to reduce and improve.  I've gone from the original query that took 180 seconds down to this that now takes about 20 seconds but its still not enough.

Can anyone offer performance improvements for this query?

We're searching through a few million rows of data so every little bit will help.

Comment: How fast does it run if you comment out the three subqueries in your select statement?

Comment: Post the output of the explain statement here.

Comment: Also, is there a featured field in item_category_xref?

Comment: What are you trying to get out?  All items that have the featured field set in item_category_xref, their viewcount and their search count?

Comment: Can't you replace the select (*) from  by a join and a group by ?

Comment: posted the explain, sorry I didn't include it the first time.  I'll think of that next time.

Answer (score 0):

Many fields which are used in your subqueries, are not part of an index. If you intend to use it in such queries a lot, try creating composite indexes corresponding to these subqueries. You might not need all of them (it depends on how big your tables are and how the data is distributed there).

Also, you didn't specify how your tracking_action table looks, but I see you are using text field there (if it is a text field), if that one is not indexed then it slows down the query too.

I would try creating (some of) the following composite indexes:

```
item_category_xref - (item_id, featured) and (item_id, category_id)
tracking_action - (context_guid, context, action)
item_image - (item_id, sequence)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would move your subqueries to more appropriate places in the overall queries.  Anything you are wanting in the results, join their subqueries to the item table.  Things you want to compare against should be in the where field.  Also, anything you are comparing in the query needs to be indexed.  The obvious one is `delete` fields, but I would include the tracking action `context_guid` and `action` fields, possibly as a composite index.  Also I would make sure to properly quote `action` in your query as it is a reserved word.

This would give you the added benefit of being able to break out each subquery and test them individually looking for performance hits.  This would allow you to isolate problematic tables or indexes.

Here is my rough staring point, the syntax may not be perfect.

```
SELECT
    itm.id "item.id",
    ws.id "workspace.id", 
    co.id "company.id",
    tav.ta_view_count,
    tas.ta_search_count
FROM item itm
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ta1.context_guid, COUNT(*) as ta_view_count FROM tracking_action ta1 GROUP BY ta1.context_guid HAVING ta1.context_guid = 'ITEM' AND ta1.`action` = 'VIEW') tav ON tav.context_guid = itm.guid
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ta2.context_guid, COUNT(*) as ta_search_count FROM tracking_action ta2 GROUP BY ta2.context_guid HAVING ta2.context_guid = 'ITEM' AND ta2.`action` = 'SEARCH_RESULT') tas ON tas.context_guid = itm.guid
WHERE   itm.deleted != 1 AND
        itm.id IN (SELECT icx.item_id, COUNT(*) featured FROM item_category_xref icx GROUP BY icx.item_id HAVING featured > 0) AND
        itm.id IN (SELECT company.id FROM company WHERE company.deleted != 1) AND
        itm.id IN (SELECT workspace.id FROM workspace WHERE workspace.deleted != 1) AND
        itm.id IN (SELECT item_image.id FROM item_image WHERE item_image.sequence != 1);
```

Comment: copy and pasted exactly what you have and it kicks back an error.
Unknown column 'ta1.action' in 'having clause'

Comment: what are the columns in your tracking_action table?  In the original query it references an action column

Comment: If ta1.action did not throw errors go ahead and remove the explicit quotes and try again.

Comment: still getting that same error but your comments and sql have helped